# Blender 2.8 cannot find libmvec.so.1

Tags: error, linux

I am running CentOS 7 and I was trying to test the latest builds of Blender. However, every time I try running it, I keep getting the following error:

`error while loading shared libraries: libmvec.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Looking online, I found out the libmvec is vector math library that was added in Glibc 2.22. Since the newest Glibc version in CentOS is 2.17, it made sense that I wouldn't have it. Therefore, I compiled a newer version of Glibc, installed it in a location different from the main one, and added the new path to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable. However, I still get the same error. It is as if Blender cannot see the new version I installed.

Is there a way I can force Blender to use the libraries from this new Glibc version? I am trying to avoid having to change distros as I have other programs that rely heavily on CentOS.

Comment: You could try to add a symlink to the new library and place it in the directory where blender is actually looking. Just a guess.

Comment: I symlinked it in `/usr/lib`, `/usr/lib64` and even in Blender's own `lib` directory and it still didn't work. I am not sure if Blender is looking for it in a different folder.

Answer (score 1):

There is a debug tool on linux: "strace"

In blender directory:

`strace ./blender-softwaregl --background`

or

`strace ./blender --background`

You can watch the system calls, e.g. the "open" calls too. It will show the path in "open" calls.

example:

```
user$ strace ./blender-softwaregl --background
..
..
open("/lib/libmvec.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/libmvec.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffe99686660) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/libmvec.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/tls", 0x7ffe99686660)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64/libmvec.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64", 0x7ffe99686660) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libmvec.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
writev(2, [{"./blender", 9}, {": ", 2}, {"error while loading shared libra"..., 36}, {": ", 2}, {"libmvec.so.1", 12}, {": ", 2}, {"cannot open shared object file", 30}, {": ", 2}, {"No such file or directory", 25}, {"\n", 1}], 10./blender: error while loading shared libraries: libmvec.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
) = 121
exit_group(127)                         = ?
+++ exited with 127 +++
```

-- UPDATE2 --

You can see the paths where "blender" tries to open the libmvec.so.1 file. Pick a path and you could try to add a symlink to the compiled glibc directory.

I don't have a CentOS 7 box, but I have an old Ubuntu machine

**-- The whole operation on Ubuntu --**

**Compile glibc-2.24 on Ubuntu 14.04:**

```
cd ~
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libc/glibc-2.24.tar.gz
tar -xvzf ./glibc-2.24.tar.gz
cd glibc-2.24
mkdir _build
cd _build
```

Your kernel version on CentOs may be different. My kernel version is 3.13. You can get your kernel version by `uname -a` command on linux.

```
../configure --enable-kernel=3.13 --prefix=/usr
make
```

If there is no error on compile, you are done.

**Symlinking**

Download blender 2.80 beta from https://builder.blender.org/download/ and extract it. Navigate to blender's main folder and:

```
cd lib
ln -s ~/glibc-2.24/_build/mathvec/libmvec.so ./libmvec.so.1
ln -s ~/glibc-2.24/_build/math/libm.so ./libm.so.6
```

**GO**

Navigate to blender's main folder.

headless version:

```
./blender-softwaregl --background --python-console
```

gui version:

```
./blender
```

It works for me on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Okay, so after I do this, then what?

Comment: I couldn't add a comment on the question because I don't have enough reputation yet. I have completed my answer.

Comment: Type `uname -a` to show kernel version.

Comment: Updated.. ```uname -a``` for kernel version of course. Thank you Nick.

Comment: I am having the same situation and I followed the instructions on the compile library and now I got stuck after I try to start blender and I get this: ./blender: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by ./lib/libGL.so.1)
./blender: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: versionGLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./lib/libGL.so.1) ./blender: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by ./lib/libGL.so.1)
./blender: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: versionCXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by ./lib/libGL.so.1) Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: @MichelMartinsZigaib - I suppose you have installed the version from your distro's repo? Try the zipped version fro blender.org instead and extract it into your home's .bin directory (or where ever you want). At some point, every distro tends to break Blender dependencies. This won't happen if you use the whole package instead.