# How to install/use Blender 2.8 on CentOS 7.6?

Tags: linux

I use Centos 7.6 and I am having issues to run Blender because there are problems with my libraries in my case "libmvec.so.1" is not found it seems that is due to the gclib version, I was looking for solutions and it seems that to solve it I would have to upgrade it which I also found that is not recommended because it is dangerous for the system.

So my question is, is there a way to use Blender in CentOS without compromising the system?

Comment: Nothing really?

Comment: I'm in the same situation as you. It is not recommended to compile yourself. I decided to wait until red hat 8 release, the beta is out and now with glibc updated to version 2.28.
Otherwise you may leave Centos temporarily and jump to another distro, like Mint.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I think to wait is the solution, for now I am using the 79b version, changing os is out of the question since my system is all setup and running good just to think in start up all over again gives me the chills.:D

Comment: It seems like their are big problems with old libraries at the moment, though some people have been able to build working versions with a fair bit of a struggle: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/unable-to-run-blender-2-80-in-rhel-centos-7/2138/64

Comment: see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120890/blender-2-8-cannot-find-libmvec-so-1?rq=1
also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132158/how-do-i-maintain-a-separate-newer-glibc-gcc-stack-as-non-root-on-linu

Comment: @MichelMartinsZigaib, could you maybe edit the question and add some more detail it?  Could you explain how you know about the problems with your libraries? Posting exact error messages and explaining when you get them might be useful. It is also helpful if you describe what you have tried up until now.