# blender 2.8 requires glibc 2.23, have 2.22

Tags: error

Forgive me if this is off topic, if it is a pointer in the right direction (appropriate location to ask) would be appreciated.  I'm trying to use blender 2.8 on an opensuse 42.3 machine.  Long story short I downloaded glibc 2.2.3 and tried configure and got

```
 configure: error: The x86_64 is not supported.
```

I downloaded blender 2.8 for linux unpacked and issued `./blender` from the command line.

```
:~/Downloads/blender-2.80-3c3d80ea22af-linux-glibc224-x86_64> ./blender
./blender: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.23' not found (required by ./blender)
```

I got the glibc version via ldd,

```
:~/Downloads/blender-2.80-3c3d80ea22af-linux-glibc224-x86_64> ldd --version
ldd (GNU libc) 2.22
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

found this to help.
[Blender 2.8 cannot find libmvec.so.1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120890/blender-2-8-cannot-find-libmvec-so-1)

So, I downloaded glibc-2.2.3 from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libc/, found the kernel version with uname -r (4.4.165-81-default).

Then I unpacked glibc-2.2.3 with tar -xzvf, entered directory, made _build directory, entered that and then issued:

```
:~/Downloads/glibc-2.2.3/_build> ../configure --enable-kernel=4.4.165-81-default --prefix=/usr
```

and got,

```
loading site script /usr/share/site/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
loading cache ./config.cache
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking sysdep dirs... configure: error: The x86_64 is not supported.
```

I am guessing that this is a problem with the *name* of the system "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu".

Also I just noticed that in the build of blender that I downloaded, there is a 
blender-2.80-3c3d80ea22af-linux-**glibc224**-x86_64 , in the name does this imply that I need glibc 2.2.4?

Any Help would be appreciated,

eh-five

Comment: Could try the [2.25 community version](https://software.opensuse.org/package/glibc)

Comment: Thanks, I looked and it appears as though the community version for 42.3 is not working.   https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/home%3Acanislycan/glibc     Also I would prefer to not install it and just use the files, like here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host

Comment: Just thought I'd add this.  I succeeded in building a git version of glibc 2.23 NOT 2.2.3 and I did get to run blender without installing glibc on the system, with a script that was packaged with glibc named, "testrun.sh".  Unfortunately, I had some other errors so blender failed.  It appears though after trying a live version, that opensuse tumbleweed will run blender 2.8 with no problems.     -eh five